# Style href for bootstrap localhost vs server name

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3

dWhen I run an ASPX page of ASP.NET web forms application using local host, as follows:

```
localhost:9010/MyLogin.aspx
```

the page is using all Bootstrap styles.  Everything works as designed.

But when I run this page using the server name, as:

```
 http//servername:9010/MyLogin.aspx
```

the page does not recognize any of the bootstrap styles.

This is how the bootstrap is referenced in the head of the page:

```
<link href="~/content/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

The physical folder where the application is installed (c:\inetpub\wwwroot\myapp) has all the sub-folders and files. As:
c:\inetpub\wwwroot\myapp\content\bootstrap\css

What could be wrong with the href above?

Comment: Is this happening in Internet Explorer?

Comment: @IrishChieftain  Yes, in IE 11

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that compatibility settings are enabled for intranet pages. Disable that from internet explorer compatibility view settings and see if it works.

Comment: It is probably it.  But I cannot change this setting. When I go to the Compatibility View Settings (this is on the customer server IE) the check box Display intranet sites in Compatibility view is checked and grayed. That is, I cannot change it.

Comment: Make sure the jQuery js file is declared before the bootstrap js file.

Comment: Yes, jQuery.js is before the bootstrap.js.  After I read your message I remembered that I had a similar issue with another client and the compatibility was the cause.  I am just waiting for the client's IT to change it for me.  Thank you for your help!